# Reading files using ifstream object - binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int *'

Tags: operator-overloading, iostream, ifstream, file-handling

I am reading a raw network file which has the following information: 
1. Arc ID
2. Tail node
3. Head node

For this I have written out the following types - arcs (has items 1,2 and 3) and networks (has an element of arc and details of total nodes and total arcs). Here is the definition:

```
typedef struct {
    int arcno;
    int tail;
    int head;
} arc_data;

typedef struct {
    arc_data *arcs;
    int numNodes;
    int numArcs;
}  network_data;
```

Now within the code I am declaring the `ifstream` object file and I am reading the data. Here network is an object of type `network_data` declared above. I am declaring arcs as a pointer because I am not sure what the total number of arcs will be until the file is read - hence needing to dynamically change the size of arcs.

```
for(i = 1; i <= network.numArcs; i++) {
    file >> &network.arcs[i].arcno;
    file >> &network.arcs[i].tail;
```

However, now the code is not building. I am using Visual Studio 2012. The compiler shows the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int *' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
51 file >> &network.arcs[i].head;
```

What is the issue here? Is there some other way than `ifstream` to read the file?

EDIT: A look at the msdn Library suggests that overloading the `>>` operator solves the issue. (Reference:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1925w4w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Can anyone please help me with writing the overloaded function?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass a pointer-to-int to the stream's extraction operator but a reference:

int i;
   cin >> i;

Some more notes:

- "binary" applies to the operator because it takes two operands. This has **nothing** to do with raw/packed binary representation as opposed to textual representation.
- C++ IOstreams are made for textual IO. They also have methods for reading/writing raw bytes, but then you have to care for the formatting yourself. This is complicated, which is why various so-called serialization libraries exist. I'd try to avoid doing it myself.
- `typedef struct { ... } name;` creates an anonymous struct and then uses typedef to give it a name. This used to be useful in C, where you could then refer to the struct as `name` while with a plain struct you had to use `struct name`, but not in C++. Drop that, it's just ugly and unnecessary.
- Yes, you can and probably should overload the insertion and extraction operators for your structures.
- I'd consider using a std::vector or similar container instead of rolling my own with a pointer/size combo.